# Data failed to import in Django models

Tags: django, django-models, python-import

I am trying to upload data using Django's import-export. The export works just fine but I have been unable to import from the frontend even though the import function works just well via the default admin dashboard. Anyone with the desire to help?

views.py:

```
def data_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        country_resource = CountryResource()
        dataset = Dataset()
        new_countries = request.FILES['datafile']

        imported_data = dataset.load(new_countries.read())
        result = country_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True)

        if not result.has_errors():
            country_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=False)

    return render(request, 'chainedModels/setup.html')
```

form:

```
{% block content %}
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="datafile">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

P.S: I also noticed that "imported_data" is being greyed out in views. When I hovered it, a popup message that "local variable 'imported_data' is not used" was displayed

**EDIT:**

For newbies like me who may encounter a similar issue in the future, here is how I solved it.

I created a form in forms.py to handle the file upload and then in my views.py, I did the following

```
def ...(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        dataform  = CountryUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if dataform.is_valid():
            country_resource = CountryResource()
            dataset = Dataset()
            file = dataform.cleaned_data['file']
            import_data = dataset.load(file.read())
            result = country_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=False)
            messages.success(request, 'Data upload was successful')
            return redirect('...')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Data upload error. Please choose a file')
            return redirect('...')
    return render(request, '...')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing you've got a typo? Code error message is actually explicit and true, you are **not** using `imported_data`. Shouldn't this `imported_data` be used to initialize your `Dataset` object?

Comment: Thank you for your response @KrazyMax. Can you please show me an example of how to go about this?

Comment: Well I don't know, I just say your error is normal, because you define a variable named `imported_data `, but you never use it! I don't know about the package you're using, but something logical at first sight would be `import_data = dataset.load(file.read())`, then `dataset = Dataset(import_data)`, not the opposite. Just read the doc of your package!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that :-) Do not hesitate to upvote and accept my answer then, so your question can be closed. Happy new year! 